# How to disable an input type=text in the following situation

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've got the following table which is build for every guest entry in a MySQL table.

```
    echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$gastId[$i]." ".$voornaam[$i].'</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name=present'.$gastId[$i].'[] value=1 onclick="setReadOnly(this)" checked></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name=present'.$gastId[$i].'[] value=2 onclick="setReadOnly(this)"></td>
            <td><input type="text"  name="artiest[]" value="'.$artiest[$i].'"></td>
            <td><input type="text"  name="titel[]" value="'.$titel[$i].'"></td>
        </tr>';
```

I would like to disable the two fields `artiest` (artist) and `titel` (title) base on the radio button present'.$gastId[$i].

I was trying to solve it with javascript, but I have little experience with javascript. Is there a way link the radio buttons and text field per row by ID or something?

```
<script language='javascript'>
<!-- //
function setReadOnly(obj)
{
    if(obj.value == 1)
    {
        document.forms[0].artiest.readOnly = 0;
    } else {
        document.forms[0].artiest.readOnly = 1;
    }
}
// -->
</script>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

### EDIT 21-10-2012

Sorry I've should have been more clear.

If the table looks like this:

```
------------------------------------------------
|  P  |  NP  | Artist        | Title           |
------------------------------------------------
|  X  |      | Enabled       | Enabled         |
------------------------------------------------
|     |  X   | Disabled      | Disabled        |
------------------------------------------------
etc
```

So the radio button of that row controls if the fields in that same row are enabled or disabled.

Comment: `artiest` is an array of input tags - do you want disable all, or only one of them? (it's not clear from your snippet of javascript)

Comment: I'm not sure `name="artiest[]"` is working how you might expect it to. You could try accessing it this way `document.forms[0]['artiest[]'].readOnly = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

just add ID to :

```
<td><input type="text"  id="artiest" name="artiest[]" value="'.$artiest[$i].'"></td>
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this will disable all the fields at once if i'm not mistaken. I've added some additional information about what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working:

I've added the ID fields to the elements.

```
    echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$gastId[$i]." ".$voornaam[$i].'</td>
            <td><input type="radio" id='.$gastId[$i].' name=present'.$gastId[$i].'[] value=1 onclick="setReadOnly(this)" checked></td>
            <td><input type="radio" id='.$gastId[$i].' name=present'.$gastId[$i].'[] value=2 onclick="setReadOnly(this)"></td>
            <td><input type="text"  id=artiest'.$gastId[$i].' name="artiest[]" value="'.$artiest[$i].'"></td>
            <td><input type="text"  id=titel'.$gastId[$i].'   name="titel[]" value="'.$titel[$i].'"></td>
        </tr>';
```

and changed the javascript:

```
function setReadOnly(obj)
{
    if(obj.value == 1)
    {
        document.getElementById("artiest"+obj.id).readOnly = 0;
        document.getElementById("titel"+obj.id).readOnly = 0;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("artiest"+obj.id).readOnly = 1;
        document.getElementById("titel"+obj.id).readOnly = 1;
    }
}
// -->
</script>
```

Thank you all for your help!